# Generic Database Viewer with the simplest Functions and Use

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to write a database viewer with the highest possible amount of supported database types. This viewer knows nothing about the database structure. Thats why I think nhibernate is nothing for me, correct?

Databases to which I have thought are MsSQL, Access, Excel, Oracle, SQLite, PostgreSql, (MySQL, ...)

I want to select a table and show all rows of it in a DataTable.

I've already started with the OleDbConnection. I just want to clarify in advance whether that is really the right way for me.

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

connection.Open();
DataTable dataTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, null });
```

Thanks Chris

Answer (score 0):

I would say define `plugin based` architecture, where user can select a database to connect with, specifyibg the *type* of it. Based on that *type* you load correct *driver* and make queries to db.

This means you need to define single generic `DataAcess` class which exposes to consumer a set of generic methods. After user choice these generic methods would refer to selected DB driver to obtain a data under the hood.